# Unable to set default text box values

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my html code of `angularjs` app

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" ng-model="myModel.text1" 
   name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name."
   data-original-title="Full Name">
```

And here is the constructor code

```
    function MyCtrl2($scope) {
         var initial = {text1: 'initial value'};
         var ini = {text2: 'initialvalue'};
         $scope.myModel = angular.copy(initial);
         $scope.myModel = angular.copy(ini);
}

MyCtrl2.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

The default value in only one text box `usr_email` is getting populated.But not in `user_name`
Can any one point what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **[angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)** as it will override the $scope.myModel when used for the second time (when copying init). Use **[angular.extend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend)** instead, to copy all properties of ini and initial to your model:

```
function MyCtrl2($scope) {
     var initial = {text1: 'initial value'};
     var ini = {text2: 'initialvalue'};
     $scope.myModel = {};
     angular.extend($scope.myModel, initial, ini);
}
```

Comment: A little shorter version would be angular.extend($scope.myModel = {}, initial, init). Saves one line ;)